# Javascript setInterval function can't repeat

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to use the setInterval function to get the data from other website every 10s.
But it can't repeat do it every 10s, just run the first time then stop.

```
setInterval(hypothes("testtest"), 10000);

function hypothes(username){  
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      var Jsonfile= JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      console.log(Jsonfile.total);
      console.log(username); 
    }
  };
  var url="https://hypothes.is/api/search?user=" + username + "&sort=created&order=asc";
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
  alert("test");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't actually set your function as a callback, you're calling it right away.

Modify the code where you set the interval as follows:

```
setInterval(function() { hypothes("testtest"); }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval(function(){hypothes("testtest")}, 10000);`

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` takes a function. You passed in the result of that `hypothes`. Try this:

```
setInterval(function() { hypothes("testtest") }, 10000);
```